# Auto crop image with transparent background to inner element?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I often have images like the one below, where a small image is positioned on a transparent background. The background can't be seen here, but it's definitely there - just download the image and see.

[image: Transparent image]

Is it possible to use any tool (Gimp or Photoshop) to automatically crop the transparent background to the borders of the inner element? For example, the size of this image is 320x200 and after cropping its size would be the size of the pink circle.

Comment: It isn't clear if you just want to use this on one image at a time, or if you want to crop like 100 images all at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open up  gimp, you can do one of two things to get your image. The first is to just use the autocrop image tool. This will crop to the box around the circle.

You can also select all the transparent area with the magic wand tool, and then go to Select->invert selection. Now you are selecting your image, and can cut/copy/paste/crop to selection.

Comment: autocrop does not work (maybe due to transparent bg), but Invert+Crop to selection works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Gimp, under the `Image` menu, `Autocrop Image`.

Comment: Funny but autocrop does not work although it was the first option I tried.